# Drop of verb to be?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In the following sentence –

**They found the most respected scientists in the kingdom – each one an expert.**

– why is the verb to be (is) dropped?

Shouldn't the sentence be "each one **is** an expert"?

Comment: Hello, Maher.  You may have been taught that it is incorrect to use anything other than a complete sentence. However, this is really only a rule of thumb, and one that proficient writers are happy to override when they judge this to be permissible. The string 'each one an expert' here is a 'sentence fragment'. Fragments are normally used in conversation (for convenience) or thrillers (for dramatic effect), but this example is a rare case that is fine in quite formal writing. I'd suggest it's better to regard 'being', which would if included sound _very_ formal, as the word dropped ...

Comment: here. / Look up 'sentence fragments' here.

Comment: Speaking of _one_ scientist, we could say "Professor Bloggs, an expert in forensic science, was called in." The part between the commas is a phrase describing the professor, and doesn't need a verb. The same applies when speaking of several scientists.